# TCP connection succeeded, Erlang distribution failed

Tags: rabbitmq, erlang

We installed Erlang Vm (erlang-23.2.1-1.el7.x86_64.rpm) and Rabbitmq server(rabbitmq-server-3.8.19-1.el7.noarch.rpm) on 3 different machines and were successful in starting the RabbitMQ server with three different clusters on 3 machines, but when we tried to cluster these rabbitmq nodes we are facing Erlang distribution failed error, googled it and found it might be due to Erlang cookie mismatch can anyone help us how to solve this mismatch issue if it is the root cause

Error message :

> Error: unable to perform an operation on node 'rabbit@keng03-dev01-ins01-dmq67-app-1627533565-1'. Please see diagnostics information and suggestions below.

The most common reasons for this are:

- Target node is unreachable (e.g. due to hostname resolution, TCP connection, or firewall issues)
- CLI tool fails to authenticate with the server (e.g. due to CLI tool's Erlang cookie not matching that of the server)
- Target node is not running

In addition to the diagnostics info below:

- See the CLI, clustering, and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more
- Consult server logs on node rabbit@keng03-dev01-ins01-dmq67-app-1627533565-1
- If a target node is configured to use long node names, don't forget to use --longnames with CLI tools

## DIAGNOSTICS

attempted to contact: ['rabbit@keng03-dev01-ins01-dmq67-app-1627533565-1']

rabbit@keng03-dev01-ins01-dmq67-app-1627533565-1:

- connected to epmd (port 4369) on keng03-dev01-ins01-dmq67-app-1627533565-1
- epmd reports node 'rabbit' uses port 25672 for inter-node and CLI tool traffic
- TCP connection succeeded but Erlang distribution failed
- suggestion: check if the Erlang cookie is identical for all server nodes and CLI tools
- suggestion: check if all server nodes and CLI tools use consistent hostnames when addressing each other
- suggestion: check if inter-node connections may be configured to use TLS. If so, all nodes and CLI tools must do that
- suggestion: see the CLI, clustering, and networking guides on https://rabbitmq.com/documentation.html to learn more

Current node details:

- node name: 'rabbitmqcli-616-rabbit@keng03-dev01-ins01-dmq67-app-1627533565-2'
- effective user's home directory: /var/lib/rabbitmq
- Erlang cookie hash: AFJEXwyuc44Sp8oYi00SOw==
  '''

Answer (score 0):

I had samer error description, in my case the erlang cookies matched among cluster nodes, but I seemed to face some case-sensitivity with the `rabbitmqctl join_cluster`-command.

With an elevated command prompt on host 2179NBXXXDP
this failed: `rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@2179ASXXX02`
and this worked: `rabbitmqctl join_cluster rabbit@2179asxxx02`
(Hostname of the latter turned out to be indeed lowercased in my case.)